# Finding Text within a image using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

```
clear
I = imread('punk.jpg');
B=blockproc(im2double(I), [4 4], @(x) std2(x.data(:)));
figure
imshow(I)
J = imresize(B, 4);

BW = im2bw(J,graythresh(J));
figure;
imshow(BW);

se = strel('line',11,90);
IM2 = imerode(BW,se);
figure;
imshow(IM2);
```

What i'm trying to do is isolate the possible text regions for future edit.

So far, i try to break the image into block and apply standard devation to each of it.

I convert it to greyscale and erode it.

Here are some examples.

[image: So far so good]
[image: no that good]
[image: why god why]
[image: make it stop guys]
[image: think i've created a monster]

So any suggestion why they don't seem to work apart from the first image?
What can i change?

Comment: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html

Comment: Very interesting problem you got there. However, remember, its VERY difficult to create an algorithm that reads all the text  independently of how is written. I would say that is not possible. Else, why would Google use Captcha? (Yes, google's algorithm are not able to recognize all the text so they give it to you to solve).

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html#creation-of-value

Comment: @nkjt That's nice but i'd rather work around my algorithm

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don't want to read the text, rather than understand where exactly the text is. I'll use a different method to recognise the text.

Comment: You need to think about what you're doing and how the text and the rest of the image is different.  e.g. standard deviation will be high in any area with a lot of variation (which is why in many of your examples there are lots of edges that aren't associated with text).

Comment: Here's an example for [showing how to detect text in natural images](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html) using the Computer Vision System Toolbox. It mainly relies on using MSER features.

Comment: @Rentonie you can also try Sobel Edge detection. It is easy once you find histogram of sobel image for both vertical and horizontal edges.